# Send details of Shipping per item in Adaptive Paypal Payments

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, magento-1.8

I have a requirement where I have to add shipping costs per item not per order of a particular supplier.

For example, if a buyer purchases three products of a supplier, each product has different shipping costs. The receiver option to add shipping details in invoice data I found is

```
receiverOptions[x].invoiceData.totalShipping
```

that means I have to sum up all the shipping costs and assign it. But I want to show shipping costs per product.
I'm accessing the api using `NVP`.
 Is there a chance I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm 90% sure you cannot do this with Paypal. Why can't you just send the total to Paypal and store the details on your server?

Comment: yes that's what i am already doing, but the requirement was to send along with transaction details to Paypal and I thought I may get an answer on stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

You could put the shipping items as actual items in the order instead of using the single shipping field.

With Adaptive Payments, you make your call to Pay using CREATE, and then you would follow that up with [SetPaymentOptions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/) to include details like order items prior to redirecting the user to PayPal.

If you're splitting the payment up between multiple receivers then you can specify the individual shipping amounts in each payment within SetPaymentsOptions.  Each payment in the transaction can have its own items, shipping, tax, etc.